# insert method for sqlite in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, insert

recordDict is a `NSMutableDictionary` whose keys are same as column names of the table.

```
-(void) insertRecord:(NSMutableDictionary *)recordDict tableName:(NSString *)table{

    @try {

        if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database)==SQLITE_OK) {

            NSMutableString *statement=[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"insert into %@ (",table];
            sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
            NSArray *keys=[recordDict allKeys];
            for (int i=0; i< [keys count]; ++i) {
                [statement appendString:[keys objectAtIndex:i]];
                int j=i+1;
                if (j == [keys count]) {
                    [statement appendString:@")"];
                }
                else
                {
                    [statement appendString:@","];
                }
            }
            [statement appendString:@" values ("];
            for (int i=0; i < [keys count]; ++i) {
                [statement appendString:[recordDict objectForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:i]]];
                int j=i+1;
                if (j == [keys count]) {
                    [statement appendString:@")"];
                }
                else
                {
                    [statement appendString:@","];
                }
            }

            const char *sqlstatement = [statement UTF8String];
            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlstatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL)== SQLITE_OK)
            {
                if (SQLITE_DONE!=sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) ) 
                {
                    NSAssert1(0,@"Error when inserting  %s",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
                }
                else 
                {
                    //NSLog(@"Data inserted Successfully");
                }
                //[recordDict release];
            }
            else {
                //NSLog(@"Failed with error");
                NSAssert1(0,@"Error when creation %s",sqlite3_errmsg(database));

            }

        }
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Error info is %@",[exception description]);
    }

}
```

this code gives the desired result and works for any table. but i want small code. can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)tableInsert:(NSString*)field1 Into:(NSString*)field2 intoTable:(NSString*)field3:(NSString*)field4
 {
char *err;

NSString *sql=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT OR REPLACE INTO 'tablename' ('f1' , 'f2','f3','f4') VALUES ( '%@','%@','%@','%@')",field1,field2,field3,field4];
NSLog(@"%@",sql);
if(sqlite3_exec(db,[sql UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &err)!=SQLITE_OK)
   {
    sqlite3_close(db);
    NSAssert(0,@"Error updating table");
   }
}
```

this is simplest and short way.

Comment: thanks. but i want a method that will work for any table with any number of columns. my code will work for any table with any number of columns, but its too large, so i want a small and efficient code

Comment: then use:   -(void)tableInsert:(NSDictionary*)fields
char *err;

NSString *sql=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT OR REPLACE INTO 'tablename' ('f1' , 'f2','f3','f4') VALUES ( '%@','%@','%@','%@')",[fields valueForKey:@"field1"],[fields valueForKey:@"field2"],[fields valueForKey:@"field3"],[fields valueForKey:@"field4"]];
NSLog(@"%@",sql);
if(sqlite3_exec(db,[sql UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &err)!=SQLITE_OK)
   {
    sqlite3_close(db);
    NSAssert(0,@"Error updating table");
   }
}

Comment: again you specified the column names

Comment: the you have to make same structure for each table and with same field name.